# Mouse works in BIOS but not in Windows

Tags: usb, mouse

No USB mouse works when plugged in the backside of my computer and when in Windows. It also don't work on the USB 3.0 ports on frontside, only the 2.0 ones. When I am in the BIOS setup, it works everywhere.

USB keyboard works only half of the time when I switch on the computer. I have checked that all cables are plugged well.

I have just cleaned the inside of my computer. And I managed to partly break a blue socket marked with "JUSB4" and "USB 3.0" on the motherboard. The cable leads to the USB connectors on the top of my case.

This picture shows the socket in question, where some of the pins are bent.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean under "partly break a blue connector"?

Comment: I accidentially bended the cable out of the socket. Some pins got bent, but I think they are all in place now inside the holes in the cable.

Comment: could be they are dry joints now ie not having a proper connection to the board itself